# How do you setup an gsp snippet in grails and with spring-security-core?

Tags: security, spring, grails, partial, gsp

I have a block of gsp I'd like to reuse and make into a little gsp snippet:

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>
    <g:link controller="user" action="showProfile">My Profile</g:link> |
    <g:link controller="privateMessage" action="list">Inbox</g:link> |
    <g:link controller="user" action="showPreferences">Preferences</g:link> |
    <g:link controller="logout" action="index">Logout</g:link>
</sec:ifLoggedIn>
<sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
    <form id="loginForm" action="/myproject/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <input type='text' name='j_username' id='username' size="15" />
            <input type='password' name='j_password' id='password' size="15" />
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button" />
            <a href="#">Register</a>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
```

I have learned that I can use g:render template="_loginStuff" to merge the template in with the rest of the markup. However, doing so with Spring Security results in an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.determineUrl(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.java:77)

at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.getAttributes(AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:76)

at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:171)

at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106)

at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188)

at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:40)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)

at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)

at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:67)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:66)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)

at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)

at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)

at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)

at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I have no idea if I am just not using  correctly, or if my template needs to be in a special folder... or if Spring-security-core will not allow  to be used at all. Help?

Comment: Well, I just made a tag lib and in the method, i just rendered the template in the code... seems to work. I guess I have to use 1 level of indirection and put up with the taglib.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the context path ("/myproject/j_spring_security_check") you should calculate it dynamically:  <form id="loginForm" action="${request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">

Comment: Thanks ;) I wanted to do that, but I didn't know what was exposed. I am totally new to grails.